# Images uploaded to Word Press are not visible except in edit

Tags: wordpress, image

I have a WordPress page hosted in BlueHost for years. Have not changed theme. old images in media library and posts are ok.

If I upload a new image it shows as a blamk square in media library and in postif included in a post. The only way to see it displayed is to go to Edit and then to Edit Inage, There it shows fine,

I have disabled all pluggins and tried everything I could google for days, even tested changing theme, Tried using a Web image instead of jpg. Checked that uploaded images were in wp-content, uploads file, etc
Tried uploading directly to post. This shows grayed image in post for a second and then it disapears with no trace,
Also tried uploading using drag and drop option. Same result